# PYODBC not committing to MS Access Desktop Database

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

So, after coding with pyodbc for a couple days now, I've run into a road block it seems. My SQL update will not work, even after putting autocommit=True in the connection statement. Nothing changes in the database at all. All my code is provided below. Please help. (I am using the 2016 version of MS Access, code runs with no errors, 32 bit Python and Access.)

```
import pyodbc

# Connect to the Microsoft Access Database
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\Databse\CPLM.accdb'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr2 = cnxn.cursor()

# SQL code used for the for statement
SQL = "SELECT NameProject, Type, Date, Amount, ID FROM InvoiceData WHERE Type=? OR Type=? OR Type IS NULL AND ID > ?"

# Defining variables
date = ""
projectNumber = 12.04
numberDate = []

# Main Code, for each row in the SQL query, update the table
for row in crsr.execute(SQL, "Invoice", "Deposit", "1"):
    print (projectNumber)
    if row.NameProject is not None:
        crsr2.execute("UPDATE Cimt SET LastInvoice='%s' WHERE Num='%s'" % (date, projectNumber))
        cnxn.commit()

        # Just used to find where to input certain data.
        # I also know all the code in this if statement completes due to outside testing
        projectNumber = row.NameProject[:5]
        numberDate.append([projectNumber, date])
    else:
        date = row.Date
print(numberDate)

crsr.commit()
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Can you print the query string?

Comment: Immediately after `crsr2.execute` you can do a `print(crsr2.rowcount)` to verify that it is non-zero.

Comment: @tay421 - use an `@` reply (like I just did) to indicate to whom you are replying.

Comment: @Erik - not exactly sure how to do that (new to programming)

Comment: @Gord Thomson when I print(crsr2.rowcount), it shows a value of 1 in the console.

Comment: Just `print("UPDATE Cimt SET LastInvoice='%s' WHERE Num='%s'" % (date, projectNumber))`

Comment: @Erik "UPDATE Cimt SET LastInvoice='1/27/2014' WHERE Num='12.04'" appears in the console after that print

Comment: And LastInvoice is a date/time field in Access, correct?

Comment: Using Erik's suggestion, just found that some dates are being input as None, most likely the source of my problem. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Erik It was just a text field to make things simple